# kohana property error

Tags: model, get, properties, kohana

i have a kohana module, describing a table that has a reference to another table.
So i declare in the 'Sale' module:

```
protected $_belongs_to = array(
    'image'     => array('foreign_key' => 'sale_picture_header'),
);
```

and then, in a get method, i say:

```
 public function __get($property)
{
blah blah
     .......
     if ($property == 'image')
    {
        return $this->image; 
    }
```

and then i call in a view

```
                <? $image = $sale->image->find(); ?>
```

but i get a weird error :

```
Notice: Undefined property: Model_Sale::$image in ...
```

(in the model) where i declare $this-> image (so it doesn't actually recognise this property an i wonder why)

why is that? the property is defined. am i missing something?

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Assuming your question is about ORM models*

There is no need to modify `__get()` method, because ORM will automatically return table columns and relations by their names. Just use `$sale->image` (without `->find()`) and you get a related model.